# Ubuntu 20.10 strange /var/log/syslog entries

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, 20.10

I just updated from Ubuntu 20.04 to 20.10, and I'm seeing these messages in /var/log/syslog, and they repeat over and over and over...

```
Nov 26 06:51:32 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[192907]: Can't update stage views actor Gjs_ui_appDisplay_AppIcon is on because it needs an allocation.
Nov 26 06:51:32 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[192907]: Can't update stage views actor StWidget is on because it needs an allocation.
Nov 26 06:51:32 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[192907]: Can't update stage views actor Gjs_ui_iconGrid_BaseIcon is on because it needs an allocation.
Nov 26 06:51:32 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[192907]: Can't update stage views actor StBoxLayout is on because it needs an allocation.
Nov 26 06:51:32 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[192907]: Can't update stage views actor StBin is on because it needs an allocation.
Nov 26 06:51:32 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[192907]: Can't update stage views actor StIcon is on because it needs an allocation.
Nov 26 06:51:32 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[192907]: Can't update stage views actor ClutterActor is on because it needs an allocation.
Nov 26 06:51:32 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[192907]: Can't update stage views actor StLabel is on because it needs an allocation.
Nov 26 06:51:32 Satellite-E55 gnome-shell[192907]: Can't update stage views actor ClutterText is on because it needs an allocation.
```

It doesn't give much of a clue, other than the fact it's gnome-shell. Normally this might be a gnome-shell extension problem, but I've disabled all of my extensions (except the normal 3 that are installed with Ubuntu), and tried turning off some Startup Applications, but yet the error persists.

Any idea where this error comes from, and what to do about it?

Comment: I see the same in my fresh Ubuntu 20.10, so at least you know it is not an issue of upgrading.

Comment: @vanadium Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Looks like a new bug: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/3098; it is closed since yesterday, and a commit is proposed (https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/commit/3fb0284358714ba72d586b918783ddead05a09f8) so hopefully that is a correction that will make it to 20.10 soon.

Comment: @vanadium I just discovered that it may have to do with the lock screen. cd to /var/log/ and type `grep -i clutter syslog` and note the last time, then lock the screen, repeat the grep, and note the time again.

Comment: @vanadium Good find! It matches what I just found about the lock screen! I just switched from 20.04 to 20.10 yesterday, and I'm disappointed at all of the major problems that I'm finding...

Comment: Just from a user perspective, I am very pleased with 20.10 as a daily driver. I am running it since almost the day it was released. I have no real "visible" issues thus far.

Comment: @vanadium Are you monitoring /var/log/syslog*? Did you fix the sssd problem (see my other question/answer)? I just added another question regarding desktop-icons.

Comment: @vanadium I can confirm that the bug (or one producing very similar syslog errors)  is alive and well in 22.04.

Comment: ... and the bug is present in Archlinux too, running on kernel 6.0.1 with GDM 42.0 on X11, ... only it's 2 years later.